# Grails 2 Show transient property that is an alias for id column

Tags: grails-orm, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class

I just started out with Grails and I have a old MSSQL DB that needs a new fancy Grails UI on top of it. So far i have this code

```
class Foo {
    version false
    columns {
        id column: 'legacy_id'
        bar column: 'legacy_column_1'
        baz column: 'legacy_column_2'
    }

    static transients = ['oldId']

    public int getOldId() { id }

    int id
    int bar
    String baz
}
```

and some extra scaffolding and so on. Everything works fins except one thing and that is that I can't get Grails to show me a column in the view with the name "Old Id" or for that matter show the column id. Whatever I tweak I always only end up with the columns bar and baz in the list view.

The internet is rather quiet on the topic so either I'm missing something obvious here and this is really simple or I have to hone my google skills...

Answer (score 0):

You need to put some of the things into a `mapping` block

```
class Foo {

  static mapping = {
    version false
    table 'old_foo'  // whatever you legacy table name is
    id column: 'legacy_id'
    bar column: 'legacy_column_1'
    baz column: 'legacy_column_2'
  }

  static transients = ['oldId']

  public int getOldId() { id }

  int id //not really needed
  int bar
  String baz
}
```

When you create the scaffolding with `generate views` or `generate all` it won't automatically add the `id` or `oldId` to the views - but you can add it yourself to ensure it's there using

```
${fooInstance.id}
${fooInstance.oldId}
```

You also don't need to have the `int id` specifically set - GORM creates it automatically.

One last thing - make sure in your DataSource.groovy file that you don't alter the database with the `dbCreate` line - I usually comment it out entirely when using legacy databases.